# Metas de compartilhamento Facebook, Google+ e Twitter

Tags: php, html, seo

Sempre que insiro metas para compartilhamentos nos sites em geral, sigo os padrões abaixo, a dúvida é a seguinte:

Existem mais metas que são consideradas importantes nestas três redes sociais que posso incluir em meus projetos, que irão melhorar sua visualização nas mesmas caso forem compartilhadas, ou somente estas já são o suficiente?

Segue metas:

```
<?php
if (isset($produto_interna)) {
    foreach ($produto_interna as $interna_produtos) {
        ?>
        <!-- para o Twitter Card -->
        <meta name="twitter:card" content="product">
        <meta name="twitter:site" content="<?php print $config_topo[0]->twitter ?>">
        <meta name="twitter:title" content="<?php print $interna_produtos->nome_produto ?>">
        <meta name="twitter:description" content="<?php print character_limiter($interna_produtos->descricao_produto, 150); ?>">
        <meta name="twitter:creator" content="<?php print $config_topo[0]->twitter ?>">
        <meta name="twitter:image" content="<?php print base_url(); ?>categoria/imagem_crop/<?php print $interna_produtos->imagem_produto ?>">
        <meta name="twitter:data1" content="R$<?php print $interna_produtos->valor_produto ?>">
        <meta name="twitter:label1" content="Preço">
        <!-- Código do Schema.org também para o Google+ -->
        <meta itemprop="name" content="<?php print $interna_produtos->nome_produto ?>">
        <meta itemprop="description" content="<?php print character_limiter($interna_produtos->descricao_produto, 150); ?>">
        <meta itemprop="image" content="<?php print base_url(); ?>categoria/imagem_crop/<?php print $interna_produtos->imagem_produto ?>">
        <!-- para o sistema Open Graph - Facebook -->
        <meta property="og:locale" content="pt_BR">
        <meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
        <meta property="og:url" content="<?php print base_url(); ?>categoria/<?php print $interna_produtos->slug_categoria ?>/<?php print $interna_produtos->slug_produto ?>"/>
        <meta property="og:title" content="<?php print $interna_produtos->nome_produto ?>">
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php print $config_topo[0]->titulo ?>"/>
        <meta property="og:description" content="<?php print character_limiter($interna_produtos->descricao_produto, 150); ?>"/>
        <meta property="og:image" content="<?php print base_url(); ?>categoria/imagem_crop/<?php print $interna_produtos->imagem_produto ?>"/>        
        <meta property="og:price:amount" content="<?php print $interna_produtos->valor_produto ?>" />
        <meta property="og:price:currency" content="R$" />
        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="123456789" />
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Aguardo sugestões.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em relação às metas, creio que estão mais que suficientes, são as principais.
O que você pode fazer para ajudar é trabalhar com dados estruturados.

Caso você não trabalhe com isso, considere trabalhar, pois é muito importante.

Por exemplo o Ratting do Schema, que exibe aquelas estrelinhas e número de votos nos resultados do Google.

Ex:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating" itemprop="aggregateRating">
    <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4.5">
    <meta itemprop="ratingCount" content="414">
</div>
```

Veja mais sobre Schemas em: http://schema.org/